# Generate Typescript output structure using "outDir"

Tags: typescript

I have a library specifically created for sharing @interfaces, @types between a client and server repository. Now I need to create a "dist" directory, however that does not work when running `tsc` (version 3.9.6)

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types" : ["node", "lodash"],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "alwaysStrict": false
  },
  "include": [
    "@interfaces",
    "@types"
  ]
}
```

After running `tsc` I expect there to be an dist folder created at the level of package.json, however this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The setting that defines the output directory is named `outDir`, inside the `compilerOptions` block.

In your case, it is set to "build".

Please see the documentation here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outDir

Comment: yes, however there is no build directory either. It is really strange as I have done this before

Answer (score 0):

This issue appeared to be a stupid mistake. All the files were .ts, but should have been .tsx